# Setting Android Activity Orientation and lock it during onStart

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have an activity that I want to lock the orientation of it based on the orientation of the device when the activity starts, I can't seem to figure it out. The code I have now is

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    }
    doStuffBasedOnOrientation();

}
```

It seems like it would only work for the first onStart then it will stop changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

To allow oreintation again use

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

You could also use this piece of code

```
private void lockOrientation() {

    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            } else {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
            } else {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
            } else {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            } else {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
            }
    }
}
```